# Stop multishipping from splitting orders in magento

Tags: php, magento

The issue:
I need to stop the multishipping core module from splitting quantities into separate orders. I almost need it to act like Cart page, where I update quantity and it won't split them. I have a customer that may order 100 items (of the same thing) for one store and 20 for another. That then creates 120 separate orders and 120 lines to go through and add addresses.

I have searched everywhere and haven't found much help. Below I believe is the code that is associated with the splitting (core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping). Also attached is what the issue is. Any direction is much appreciated.
ver 1.7

```
protected function _addShippingItem($quoteItemId, $data)
{
     $qty       = isset($data['qty']) ? (int) $data['qty'] : 1;
    //$qty       = $qty > 0 ? $qty : 1;
    $addressId = isset($data['address']) ? $data['address'] : false;
    $quoteItem = $this->getQuote()->getItemById($quoteItemId);

    if ($addressId && $quoteItem) {
        /**
         * Skip item processing if qty 0
         */
        if ($qty === 0) {
            return $this;
        }
        $quoteItem->setMultishippingQty((int)$quoteItem->getMultishippingQty()+$qty);
        $quoteItem->setQty($quoteItem->getMultishippingQty());
        $address = $this->getCustomer()->getAddressById($addressId);
        if ($address->getId()) {
            if (!$quoteAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddressByCustomerAddressId($address->getId())) {
                $quoteAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($address);
                $this->getQuote()->addShippingAddress($quoteAddress);
            }

            $quoteAddress = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddressByCustomerAddressId($address->getId());
            if ($quoteAddressItem = $quoteAddress->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItemId)) {

                $quoteAddressItem->setQty((int)($quoteAddressItem->getQty()+$qty));
            } else {
                $quoteAddress->addItem($quoteItem, $qty);
            }
            /**
             * Require shiping rate recollect
             */
            $quoteAddress->setCollectShippingRates((boolean) $this->getCollectRatesFlag());
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone else has this issue I was able to figure it out. I was in the wrong function.

**getQuoteShippingAddressesItems()**

Located in core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Multishipping.php around line 116.

Changed the following code:

```
for ($i = 0, $n = $item->getQty(); $i < $n; $i++)
```

To

```
for ($i = 0, $n = 1; $i < $n; $i++)
$addressItem->setQty($item->getQty)
```